# How can I add some text on the head of an a existing file .csv without overwriting?

Tags: python

I'm trying to add some text on the head of my file without overwriting is there any solution to do it with python. My file is already full.

Comment: you can't add anything in any file. You have to create new file, first write head and next write all other data from old file. Or you have to read all to memory and write all back to the same file - with head at start. You can't move elements in file to create place for head.

Comment: Can you provide a code of what you already tried? The snippet would be helpful to fully understand the problem you have.

Comment: cols =['COMPANY_NAME','Test_Budget_in_MAD','MONTH','YEAR',worksheet.cell(0,-1).value]
list_t.reverse()
df = pd.DataFrame(list_t,columns=cols)
df.to_csv('File_Name.csv',sep=';',index=False)
df.head(len(df))

f = open('File_Name.csv', "w")
f.write('Test'+str(len(df)) +"\n")
f.close()

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import os 

text = 'add_text'
file_name = 'file_name.csv'
os.rename(file_name, text + file_name)
```